# Custom Layout Update XML on Product page

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, theme, xml, layout-update

I have simple question about custom layout update. I would like to add static block on product page using Product custom layout update but it doesn't work for me.

I've tried to use this code:

```
<reference name="product.info">
   <block type="cms/block" name="slider" as="slider" before="-">
      <action method="setBlockId">
         <block_id>slider</block_id>
      </action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's because **by default the template does not render all its child blocks.**

To fix that you need to edit the `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` file and add the following line where you want your custom block to be displayed:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('slider') ?>
```

Comment: okay, understood. But, do we have some other way for it? because I would like to use 5-6 different static blocks for different products? How can I show block without `getChildHtml`?

Comment: @Oleg Unfortunately that's the only way I'm aware of.

Comment: thank you. In this case I guess I have to play with attributes

Comment: @Oleg What you can do, is call `getChildHtml()` without parameters, it will render all children

Comment: @fschmengler I wanted to post that as well but I ended up not doing it in case other modules were adding blocks to this block and the corresponding `getChildHtml('blockname')` was not here ;)

Comment: @fschmengler thanks, but i already fixed it. I've created 3 new text attributes for configurable products and pasted static blocks id for every products which i need.

Answer (score 1):

Other way that you can try is as below :

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_static_block_id')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Place this code directly in your phtml file where you want to show the static block on the frontend.

If you want different blocks for different products, you can create the static blocks based on the sku. 
Suppose there are two products Product A with sku SA and Product B with sku SB, now create two static blocks with ids SA and SB respectively now call them on the catalog/product/view.phtml in your theme using below code.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($_product->getSku())->toHtml(); ?>
```

Other way that you can try is add update handle, you can refer the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735522/magento-template-based-on-attribute-set

Comment: no, it's not what i asked. I need to show different static blocks for different products

Comment: You can create the static blocks based on the product sku and on the product template file you can pass the sku as the dynamic variable as the block id, if you are creating different blocks for different products.